# Returning unique indices for given value in python

Tags: python, indices, enumerate

I have a list where I need to extract index number of all elements based on given unique value.

If I apply:

```
test3 = ["P3","P35","P35","P3","P2"]
actual_state = "P3"
indexes = [n for n, x in enumerate(test3) if actual_state in x]
```

this returns:

```
[0, 1, 2, ,3]
```

But output should be:

```
[0, 3]
```

P3 exists in P35 as well, renaming P35 won't help since I have nested list with thousands of inputs, any advice how can I extract this in desired way ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `in` to `==`, because `in` test substrings also:

```
indexes = [n for n, x in enumerate(test3) if actual_state == x]
print (indexes)
[0, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group indices of unique strings, then just access the key of `actual_state`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

test3 = ["P3","P35","P35","P3","P2"]
actual_state = "P3"

d = defaultdict(list)
for i, test in enumerate(test3):
    d[test].append(i)

print(d[actual_state])
# [0, 3]
```